# Google translate API Text is too long error

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I am trying to translate tweets extracted from a Mysql db with the Google Cloud Translate API.  I have gotten the Python3 script working with a small number of tweets.

I now want to scale up with a larger number of tweets per API call, starting modestly with 1000. Relevant code is:

```python
import html
import collections
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
from os import environ
from google.cloud import translate

db = pymysql.connect(host = "****",user = "****",password = "****",db = "****", charset="utf8mb4", cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor, autocommit=True)

project_id = environ.get("PROJECT_ID", "")
assert project_id
parent = f"projects/{project_id}"
client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

tweets = list();
tids = list();

cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "select tid,orig from translate where translated is null limit 1000"
cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()
charcount = 0
maxlen = 0;
for i in range(len(results)):
    tweets.append(results[i]['orig'])
    l = len(results[i]['orig'])
    charcount += l
    if l > maxlen:
        maxlen = l
    tids.append(results[i]['tid'])
response = client.translate_text(contents=tweets,target_language_code='en',parent=parent,)
```

When I call the API I'm getting a "Text is too long" error. The value of charcount is 91825 and maxlen is 143. So I don't see where I'm running afoul of the [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas). How to track down the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what mysql has to do with this -- why not hardcode the data that's failing the quota in the interests of a [mcve]? Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe I can post the actual tweets due to Twitter's terms of use (it's purchased data). I did find that it runs OK with limit of 300 on the mysql query.  I still don't understand why more than that violates the quota, but I guess it does somehow.

Comment: The content isn't important -- it could be made up lorem ipsum text. The key is that it's runnable so others can reproduce the problem. But if the code requires access to a database we don't have, then it's pretty hard to offer much help.

Comment: You can check your quotas page in your GCP console. Go to "IAM & Admin" -> "Quotas", in the "Filter box" type in "translate" so you can check the quota you are hitting. https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#viewing_all_project_quotas